# Battery saver (and Night mode) on Android 9 Pie relaunches whole activity, how to prevent this?

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie, battery-saver, android-night-mode

When I run my app on device (Google Pixel 2) with Android 9 Pie and switch on (or switch off) battery saver, whole activity immediately relaunches.
When I switch on battery saver on lower versions of Android like 6, 7 and 8, app continues normally without relaunching. Is it possible to prevent these relaunches on Android 9 too?

I investigated it and found, that when you switch on Battery saver, even new native Night mode is switched on automatically. So I tried to switch on only Night Mode via "Settings - Developer Options" and it relaunched activity in the same way as switching on Battery Saver. So this relaunching can be caused by Night mode.

*Note: don't confuse "Night light", "Dark theme" and "Night Mode", these are different things and problem is only with "Night mode".*

This is stacktrace from debugger, where can be seen, that OS tries to relaunch activity by stopping it (and then it creates it again).

```
onStop:579, MyActivity (com.mypackage)
callActivityOnStop:1432, Instrumentation (android.app)
performStop:7375, Activity (android.app)
callActivityOnStop:4181, ActivityThread (android.app)
handleRelaunchActivityInner:4796, ActivityThread (android.app)
handleRelaunchActivity:4732, ActivityThread (android.app)
execute:69, ActivityRelaunchItem (android.app.servertransaction)
executeCallbacks:108, TransactionExecutor (android.app.servertransaction)
execute:68, TransactionExecutor (android.app.servertransaction)
handleMessage:1816, ActivityThread$H (android.app)
dispatchMessage:106, Handler (android.os)
loop:193, Looper (android.os)
main:6718, ActivityThread (android.app)
invoke:-1, Method (java.lang.reflect)
run:493, RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller (com.android.internal.os)
main:858, ZygoteInit (com.android.internal.os)
```

I read here https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/power, that on new Android there are some changes in Battery Saver, but I didn't find any details and any advices for fixing possible problems.
Can you please help me?

**Actual result**: I run my app and switch on/off battery saver -> whole main activity relaunches, so it is stopped and then it tries to run as newly created.

**Expected result**: I run my app and switch on/off battery saver -> nothing happens with my app, it continues with it's main activity as nothing happened.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out by myself, so posting answer here (it is from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25626:))
To fix this problem, place uiMode in the list of android:configChanges in your AndroidManifest.

```
           <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:launchMode="singleTop"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|uiMode"
                  android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```

It is because uiMode value prevents app from restarting because of night mode (or putting in the dock too).